# why my application is no longer visible on the App Store for some users?

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile

I started flutter development some time ago, I encountered a problem with the production on Apple Store. I've updated the application and some people can't find it on the store but others can.

Even those who don't have the correct IOS version can see the application, but some who have the required IOS version can't see it in the App Store or access the application via the link.
ps: They are in the right geographical area

I've tried another production run by changing the minimum IOS version (from 16.3 to 16.2), but I have the same problem. eg: a user with IOS 16.7 can't find the application on the store, even though an IOS 16.6 can see it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try uploading a new build of your app, even if you have not made any changes to the code. This can sometimes force the App Store to update its index.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have uploaded a new build, i'm waiting the validation. I hope this will resolve my problem